# Проблемы с возвращаемыми данными GetPerTcpConnectionEStats

Tags: c#, winapi, api

Пытаюсь получить данные о сетевой статистики для определенных процессов из GetPerTcpConnectionEStats (WinAPI) но он возвращает какие то чудовищные значения, которые непонятно как обрабатывать, последовательность действий следующая

1. Устанавливанию счетчик на начало считывания

   ```
       var rodPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TCP_ESTATS_DATA_ROD_v0)));
       var ret = SetPerTcpConnectionEStats(ref _rowTCP, TCP_ESTATS_TYPE.TcpConnectionEstatsBandwidth, rodPtr, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(rodPtr), 0);
   ```
2. Считаю данные

   ```
       var rodPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TCP_ESTATS_DATA_ROD_v0)));
       var ret = GetPerTcpConnectionEStats(ref _rowTCP,TCP_ESTATS_TYPE.TcpConnectionEstatsBandwidth, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0,IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0,rodPtr, 0,rodSize);
   ```
3. Получаю во такие супер значения, с которыми не понятно как работать
   [image: Результат]

> Как мне понять сколько процесс получил по сети а сколько отправил

Comment: [0] и [1] - это принято и отправлено байт, что с этим не так? И вы используете API функцию, которая дает информацию по TCP соединениям, а не по приложениям. Попробуйте сначала получить список соединений, открытых приложением, затем получать информацию по каждому из них, затем суммировать в рамках приложения.

Comment: А разве MIB_TCPROW _rowTCP не определяет от кого именно мы хотим получит информацию, а какую тогда функцию использовать для приложений